# UITextField textInputMode returns nil when emoji keyboard is select problems

Tags: ios, swift

I notice that when autocorrection is off either by user control or hard coded the height of the alphanumeric keyboard differs from that of the emoji keyboard which was causing strange behavior with my autolayout constraints. To deal with this problem I create a NSNotification to listen when the textInputMode changed which returns "en-US" when alphanumeric keyboard is selected but returns nil when the emoji keyboard is selected.

Is this a bug with ios or is my code wrong?

Some code for reference.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // Create the notification listener 
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(inputModeDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChange, object: nil)
}

@objc func inputModeDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
  // Print the current input mode
  // textField is a UITextField variable 
  print(textField.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage as Any)
}
```

Comment: I observed that the keyboard sends two such notifications when the user taps a key for the first time during the lifetime of the app. After the first notification, primaryLanguage returns the default language of the keyboard, independently of the sequence of keyboard languages in the Settings app. After the second notification, primaryLanguage returns the actually selected keyboard language. Whenever the user changes the language through the "world" key, it sends another notification. primaryLanguage then returns the new language, and nil if an emoji keyboard was selected. Making sense?